# Call .svc through SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, httpwebrequest, soap-client

I want to write test for .svc through Soap. can any one help me to create HTTPWebRequest for call .svc action.

below is my Sample code

```
 var url = "http://localhost:4000/SI.WS.Core/SIF/CaseService.svc";
  var action = "http://localhost:4000/SI.WS.Core/SIF/CaseService.svc/GetCases";

 internal static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
```

Comment: Well considering a .svc file is a WCF-specific SOAP implementation, why not just make a WCF client test harness.  VS will even code-generate the proxy client.  No tedious mucking about in hypersp' erm I mean `HttpWebRequest` APIs

Comment: Some clients are using my WCF service through SOAP. so i wanted to write test cases for test the same way customer use.

Comment: All your cliients are using SOAP. Manually implementing a WSDL doesn't seem very useful. Maybe take a look at SoapUI.

Comment: @henk Agree, but wanted to write test case which i can run on customer environment too. using SOAP UI i cant run all test cases manually. i am gong to write generic code which will create soap envelope from object. and will call service method through soap. Please help me out with create Http web request for .svc

Answer (score 0):

```
internal  HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            var username = "xxxxx";
            var password = "xxxxx";


            byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(
                    username + ":" +
                    password);
            webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] =
                    "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);

            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
```